# how to sort a cell array in descending order in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, cell

[image]how to sort a cell array in descending order in matlab  ? I have this code for cell array

```
 ra=0;
            rank=cell(50,1);
              for i=1:50
            for j=1:50;
                 if users{j,i}~='-';
                  ra=ra+1;
                end
            end
            rank{i,1}=ra;
            ra=0;
              end
```

Comment: Give an example of your cell array's contents. And: do you want to sort rows in lexical order? Sort each column?

Comment: It is just one column and I want it to be added in rank cell array sorted in descending order every time I run. I added a picture of the cell aray.

Comment: One approach - `num2cell(sort(cell2mat(IN),'descend'))`

Answer (score 0):

let `l` be the name of your cell array. You can do this:

```
sortedl = num2cell(sort(cell2mat(l,'descend')));
```

Another way is to use:

```
sortedl = flipud(sortrows(l,1));
```